# in python, i am using pandas to read a csv file when its working fine tho with other functions but facing an error while using a line

Tags: python, pandas, variables, linear-regression

i imported panda as pd

```
   dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Adminis....')

   dataset.plot(x='tempmin', y='tempmax', style='o')
   pit.show()
   
   pit.figure(figsize=(15,10)) #these are working fine
   pit.tight_layout()
   seaborninstance.distplot(dataset['tempmax'])
   pit.show()
   but i am getting in trouble while using this
   x = dataset['tempmin'].values.reshape(-1,-1)
   y = dataset['tempmax'].values.reshape(-1,-1)

   x = dataset['tempmin'].values.reshape(-1,-1)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ValueError: can only specify one unknown dimension
```

i was expecting to use this to train my algo but i am stuck on a variable??

Comment: Which shape should be the result of the `reshape` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one dimension size can be unspecified in `reshape` function. I guess you want to convert the dataframe columns to column vectors to feed into some training module, then you need to reshape to (-1, **1**) not (-1, **-1**), i.e.

```
   x = dataset['tempmin'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
   y = dataset['tempmax'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks bro i forget to minus that yea you're  right i wanna feed into training module